# Error when fetching a Backbone Collection: A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I try to fetch a simple Backbone Collection, but I get the following error.

> A "url" property or function must be specified

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({url: '/path/toCollection'});
var collection = new Collection([]);
app.vent.bindTo('applicationDidBecomeActive', collection.fetch);
app.vent.trigger('applicationDidBecomeActive');
//Error: A "url" property or function must be specified
```

Comment: don't see how 'var collection.fetch()' could work, remove the var declaration on that line. Apart from that, this should work. Are you using vanilla Backbone? did you overwrite Backbone.sync? are you using 0.9.2 or the latest from master ?

Comment: Its normal vanilla Backbone. Seems the url gets lost somewhere between initialization and fetching. Will dig in this.

Comment: Seems it has to do with the way I call fetch in a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to bind the 'this' parameter perhaps?

```
app.vent.bindTo('applicationDidBecomeActive', collection.fetch, collection);
```